# Object deforming when I try to transform it

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, edit-mode

I'm new to Blender and I was making a helmet piece. I wanted to scale it down, but it gets deformed when I try to scale it. I found if I try to rotate, or transform the object in any way it gets deformed.
**Does anyone know how to fix this?**

I tried setting origin to the center of mass, doesn't work. Even odder, it behaves like a piece of putty in a box, it only deforms to the outer edges of itself. Here's half the helmet:
[image]

What happens when I move it:

[image]

If I try to move it far enough, it just squishes to one side:

[image]

Edit here's the file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ECEj_1Yb9A0vfmynuykhGMt-DrFTmxRU/view?usp=sharing

Edit 2: Got it!! Thanks to Nascent Space! I forgot to apply the modifiers

Comment: Do you have any modifiers on your object? Try applying them first before rotating or scaling. You can also try applying the scale or rotation of the object by pressing Shift+A.

Comment: please provide blend file